# Spring JPA Query: Use like with number

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use predicate LIKE with number. I successfully did this with just using the below code:

```
cb.like(cb.lower(entity.get("STARTED_TIME)),
                        MessageFormat.format("%{0}%", stringValue))));
```

I tried recreating this for another logic it doesn't work.
Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
cb.like((cb.function(DAYS_BETWEEN, LocalDateTime.class,
                    entity.get(STARTED_TIME),
                    entity.get(FINISHED_TIME))
                    .as(String.class)),
                MessageFormat.format("%{0}%", stringValue)));
```

There's no error when I use the above code so I dont really know whats the problem is. But it doesnt return anything and ofcourse before I execute the code I made sure that there is a matched record.

Comment: How does th e generated SQL look like?

Comment: it looks like this >>> OR (SECONDS_BETWEEN(t1.STARTED_TIME, t1.FINISHED_TIME)) LIKE '%00:00%')

Comment: and this works if you execute it in the database?

Comment: Additionally I don't understand why you are using like.

Comment: havent tried it in the database yet. im using LIKE because i have to search across the columns using a keyword.

Comment: You should always check the SQL if it works in the DB

Comment: I updated the questions above.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: your code explicitly asks for SECONDS_BETWEEN. I never queried JPA this way, but if you can't enter something like DAYS_BETWEEN, then I'd parse the seconds to requested format myself.

Comment: SECONDS_BETWEEN is just a variable name.  I tried changing the integer.class to localdatetime.class but it still wont work.